# How to generate a Graph out of an Image, with pixels as nodes and conditional edges

Tags: python, network-programming, networkx

I have a binary gray image of 0 ad 1. I would like to create a graph where every node is a pixel (of value 1) and to create an edges between every pixels that have the ecluidean distance under a threshold.

Basically I was using the `networkx` library, but the way I implemented it is very very slow (the part of edges building). There is a faster implementation of the code (lower complexity)?

```
G = nx.Graph()

rows = img.shape[0]
columns = img.shape[1]

# Generatig Nodes
for x in range(0, rows):
    for y in range(0, columns):
        if img[x, y] == 1:
            G.add_node(n, px=(x, y))

# Generating Edges based on the max distance allowed
max_dist = 10  # threshold 
for x in G.nodes:
    for y in G.nodes:
        dist = distance.euclidean(G.nodes[x]['px'], G.nodes[y]['px'])
        if dist <= max_dist:
            G.add_edge(x, y, weight=dist)
```

Note that I save the pixel labels because I need after to reconvert the graph into an image

Comment: Isn't it easier to directly add the "right neighbours"? For example, if your threshold is set such that only the neighbouring pixels need to be added. You can always add their ids. In any way you would only need to determine the neighbouring set once and then use it. In networkx, your node ids also don't need to be integers. Sou you could start with (x,y) as node id and then (if needed) relabel it to integers.

Comment: @Sparky05 I need all nodes to be added in the Graph, that is actually a not fully connected one. But I need edges only between pixels that are near...